# When test in Qual-E page-->ETC-->Key Event,the time measurement don't be showed while long pressing Up key

Tags: cobalt

When we test in Qual-E page,https://2018-dot-qual-e.appspot.com ,-->ETC-->Key Event,the time measurement don't be showed while long pressing Up key,then,back to Qual-E home page.Is this normal behavior?

Comment: For questions about YouTube certification please refer to your YouTube account manager.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a test case bug. I will fix it but please work with your YouTube technical account manager for the certification related issues going forward.

This has nothing to do with Cobalt.

Comment: I got it.Thank you for your comment